# How to stop an update if an element is unverified

Tags: php, sql, button, sql-update

I have a problem with my update. I update my stock removing the quantity necessary to make my food (stock = stock - :quantity) and if my stock `<=0` I print that I don't have enough element to make the food.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT ingredients.stock as stock,
           composition.id_ingredient,composition.quantite 
            rom composition 
            join ingredients on(composition.id_ingredient = ingredients.id) 
            where id_recette = 1;";

$response1 = $db->query($query1);
$response1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
foreach ($response1 as $row1) {
    $persons1[] = $row1;
}
$response1->closeCursor();
?>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['burger1']) AND $_GET['burger1'] == 'fabriquer') {
    foreach ($persons1 as $ET10) {
        if($ET10['stock'] - $ET10['quantite']<0){
            echo "Stock insuffisant de: ".$ET10['id_ingredient'];
    ;
        }
    }else if($ET10['stock'] - $ET10['quantite']>=0){
        $req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock - :quantite WHERE id = :ingredient");
        $req->execute(array(
                'quantite' => $ET10['quantite'],
                'ingredient'  => $ET10['id_ingredient'])
            );
    }
?>
<?php 
}
?>
```

The problem is that I print the message, if I click in my button "fabriquer", it will continue to update other element that their (stock - quantity) are >0. But I want to say that it's impossible to make the food if we don't have stock enough. So I want to stop the update if 1 element can't be update.

Thanks to read me!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the condition  in the where clause for update

```
UPDATE ingredients 
SET stock = stock - :quantite 
WHERE id = :ingredient
AND stock >=  :quantite
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check constraint, so the *database* ensures the data integrity, not the application.

```
alter table ingredients add constraint chk_ingredients_stock_gt_0
    check (stock >= 0);
```

Check constraints are actually enforced starting in MySQL 8.0.16.